# MySQL Condicion para devolver resultados que hagan match parcial con un atributo (string)

Tags: mysql

He creado un procedimiento en el que se introduce un string,n, y se devuelven los resultados cuyo atributo country_name haga match total o parcial con el valor introducido en n al llamar al procedimiento. Ejemplos:

- Se llama al procedimiento asignando n = Australia, y se devuelven los resultados cuyo country_name = Australia
- n = land, se devuelve cualquier country_name tipo: NetherLANDs, SuitzerLAND etc.

Entonces éste es el procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_ppl_visited_country(n varchar(50)) 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
    SELECT p.personID, p.personname, ci.name, h.dateArrived, co.Name 
    FROM person p 
    INNER JOIN hasvisitedcity h ON p.personID = h.personID 
    INNER JOIN city ci ON h.cityID = ci.ID 
    INNER JOIN country co ON ci.CountryCode = co.Code 
    WHERE co.Name IN (SELECT co.Name 
        WHERE LOCATE(n, co.Name) !=0);
   END//
```

Y cuando llamo al procedimiento:

```
CALL get_ppl_visited_country(land);
```

pero me da éste error y no entiendo por qué:

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'land' in 'field list'

Comment: Envíanos el resto del código SQL para poder ver qué estás haciendo exactamente. ¿Has valorado utilizar la función `LOCATE()`?

Comment: Este es el procedimiento

`CREATE PROCEDURE get_ppl_visited_country(n varchar(50))
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 SELECT p.personID, p.personname, ci.name, h.dateArrived, co.Name
 FROM person p
 INNER JOIN hasvisitedcity h
  ON p.personID = h.personID
 INNER JOIN city ci
  ON h.cityID = ci.ID
 INNER JOIN country co
  ON ci.CountryCode = co.Code
 WHERE co.Name IN (
  SELECT co.Name 
        FROM country co
        WHERE co.Name LIKE CONCAT('%', n, '%'));
END//



call get_ppl_visited_country(land)//  `

Comment: Porque la función LOCATE() busca la posición del primer match econtrado entre el string problema y la substring introducida.  Lo que yo busco es que se muestren sólo los resultados cuyo atributo country_name hagan match con el valor de n introducido al llamar la función. X ej. si n = land, se muestran sólo los resultados cuyo country_name incluya el string ´land´ tipo: NetherLANDs, SuitzerLAND etc.

Comment: Si usas `LOCATE()` en el `WHERE` conseguirás eso mismo :)

Comment: Vaya pues los intentos que hago terminan en error. He puesto la query actualizada arriba para que se vea más claro. Eso como si buscara un atributo llamado land, que es el valor que le doy a n al llamar al procedimiento, pero no entiendo por qué 

`WHERE co.Name IN (SELECT co.Name 
        WHERE LOCATE(n, co.Name) !=0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te paso un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que lo puedas reproducir:

```
CREATE TABLE paises(
  pais varchar(63)
  );

INSERT INTO paises (pais)
  VALUES ('NetherLANDs'),('SuitzerLAND '),('Spain');

SELECT * FROM paises WHERE LOCATE('land',pais);
```

No hace falta ningún `!=0`, de eso ya se encarga el propio `WHERE`:

O, como quieres hacer en tu procedimiento almacenado:

```
SELECT * FROM paises WHERE pais IN (
    SELECT pais FROM paises WHERE LOCATE('land',pais)  
  );
```

El error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'land' in 'field list'

Te aparece porque estás usando `land` sin las comillas y lo interpreta como el nombre de un campo en vez de un literal.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_ppl_visited_country(n varchar(50)) 
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM paises WHERE pais IN (
        SELECT pais FROM paises WHERE LOCATE(n,pais)  
      );   
  END;

CALL get_ppl_visited_country('land');
```

Si necesitas que comprobemos tu código, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar).

Comment: Madre mía, pensé que al haber declarado n como un string no había que poner  comillas al llamar la función. Gracias!